# iOS function to be called once (when application is initialized)

Tags: objective-c, ios, viewdidload

I have an iOS application. Application has 2 different views: Main and Settings. In fact, application needs to load and initialize some library and framework before it is used in Main View.

When I put this initialization in `viewDidLoad` method, it works OK. But when go to Settings and come back to Main View, initialization starts again, which is not what I want, and application results in a memory problem.

I need an method that is called once when application is started. Any idea?

EDIT: I switched to tabbed view. It loads views once. This is another solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this one:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

It should be in your appdelegate class.

Hope it helps

Comment: But for your application quick startup you must avoid running big threads inside the `didFinishlaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: I agree with @chiLLer. I need a method to call inside ViewController.

Comment: You meant your applications initial launch only you have to initialise the things right. if you do it inside the `viewDidLoad` obviously it 'll be called for every time you load it, Here all you need is to remember whether you have opened it alresdy or not. for this you can maintain plist or NSUserDefault key value pair or even a global variable in the `appDelegate` to remember the state....

Comment: Set a flag in your app delegate in the place @Novarg is talking about, and reset it in your view controller's viewDidXXXX, previously checking the flag.

Answer (score 28):

You state in one of your comments that you don't want to put this code in `application:didFinishLaunching` and you want to keep it in viewDidLoad. You can use this snippet to run your code only the first time is is invoked:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    // code here
});
```

The inner block will only be executed once. If the view is loaded again, the block is not called. Note that there is an Xcode code snippet for this which you can access by starting to type `dispatch_once` in the editor:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really great answere @Mike Weller

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
+ [NSObject initialize]
```

Define a class method of that name, and it will be run once before any other messages are sent to that class:

```
+ (void)initialize {
  // Put one-time initialization code here.
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate`, one of the objects guaranteed to have only one instance (singleton) throughout the app, you can declare an instance variable/property:
`BOOL initialized;`

And then in `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController`, you check if it's the code has been initialized; if not, then run the code and set the variable to true:

```
 if (!initialized) {
    // Code goes here
    initialized = true;
 }
```